# Area enclosed by curve

Tags: integration, area, curves

What is the area enclosed by the curve $$(x^2+y^2-1)^3 = x^2y^3$$
I am guessing this is solvable via double integration or perhaps polar but I am unsure of where to begin. I have tried isolating $y$ but this yields a complicated function which is difficult to integrate. Is it possible there is a way to transform a graph with known area such as a circle to yield the figure given by the equation from which the Jacobian can be calculated to find the scaling factor?

Do the sharp points at $(0,1)$ and $(0,-1)$ cause any problems?

Comment: Converting to [polar coordinates](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28-1+%2B+r%5E2%29%5E3+-+r%5E5+cos%5E2%28θ%29+sin%5E3%28θ%29%3D0)?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2527983/finding-the-area-inside-an-implicitly-defined-curve-x2-y-sqrt3x2?noredirect=1.

Comment: @TymaGaidash umm... it's not that simple, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea espoused in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2528020/357390) works here too.
$$(x^2+y^2-1)^3=x^2y^3\implies y=\frac{x^{2/3}\pm\sqrt{x^{4/3}-4(x^2-1)}}2\,dx$$
$$A=2\int_0^{a^{3/2}}\sqrt{x^{4/3}-4x^2+4}\,dx$$
Substitute $t=x^{2/3}$:
$$A=3\int_0^a\sqrt{t(t^2-4t^3+4)}\,dt=3.66197272581827\dots$$
Here $a=1.09066\dots$ is the only real root of $t^2-4t^3+4$.

While this can theoretically be expressed through *complete* elliptic integrals (since the integral runs from zero to zero of the quartic), the resulting form is so complicated that it's not worth it. I did it anyway, and this is the result as [Mathematica code](https://tio.run/##hZE9a8MwEIb3/IqDQsmHjCydrMhDCx0ylEII7dBBKOAY44rGdquqECj57e7ZLpkC3e7jfZ87nZoivlVNEX1Z9P0u@DZahO1jG6s6FLGyL58h2jiPe5mouMeVWjgGP5FByuC566h36TDhzgxeu/Du23oXqtJ/@a5N7rPUuVmAOxhZo@lEejyRU6xRMhAkaEgguIQVPBzr6hAKX26/m0MVbKCBNC0RPNfj3MRo5AYFTqmY4rObtf8y1lwaM0FQadKqXKXmDzMlxBkXDVw6jhKWMMfl5nj0H3SkjW0cJFfx9A5FpGyEyTN5L66nwbWaXXMlOpdmMGgtpCC/QJNpKqhUIdEyJRUVc5kRkRbRaqkQFxf0ztuWQeMWwDls7Q2ja98O8fiXff8L):

```
Print[3 NIntegrate[Sqrt[t(t^2-4t^3+4)], {t, 0, Root[t^2-4t^3+4,1]}, WorkingPrecision->50]]
r = Sqrt[Root[x^3+3x^2-1732, 1]]
m = 1/2 + AlgebraicNumber[r, {0, -1/96, 0, -863/83136, 0, 1/83136}]
n = 1/2 + AlgebraicNumber[r, {0, -7/288, 0, -3461/249408, 0, 1/249408}]
Sqrt[r/2]/32 * (3*EllipticE[m] - AlgebraicNumber[r, {2, 48, 5, 0, 2}]/3*EllipticK[m] +
AlgebraicNumber[r, {-69280, 2661218, 138560, 4043, 55424, 1925}]/(3*64*433)*EllipticPi[n, m]) // N[#,50]& // Print
```